# Cooperative Game Theory specialized forum

Tags: game-theory

I am looking for research-focused Game Theory forum, especially in Cooperative Game Theory. As it sometimes happen google provides links on either conferences (as opposed to online forums) or forums where students make their homework. 
Could anyone suggest one?

Comment: OK, I know it's a difficult question. Could you just suggest a forum of mathematical scientists?

Comment: A lot of game theory research is done in economics.

Answer (score 1):

The following sites/blogs while not confined to cooperative game theory have lots of pointers to recent papers and conferences that deal with the rapidly evolving new results in game theory (and mechanism design and mathematical economics): (Center For Rationality at Hebrew University) http://www.ratio.huji.ac.il/dp.php  (A blog run by Noam Nissan) http://agtb.wordpress.com/  (blog run by Alvin Roth) http://marketdesigner.blogspot.com/

Comment: Thank you very much for useful blogs. But I need forums (as opposed to blogs), do you know one?

Answer (score 1):

> **Shameless Advertisement:** [Game Theory proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47845/game-theory?referrer=MGta8a5T8SlJlb1swuXPYQ2) 
>   on Area 51 that you should totally follow!

I would answer the question, but my shameless advertisment is the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a well known and respected forum about Game Theory:
http://levine.sscnet.ucla.edu/bin/workshops-php/discuss/discuss.php3

and a good reference site too:

http://www.scienceclarified.com/Ga-He/Game-Theory.html